# Neo4j cypher query to return relationship property and sum of all matching relationship properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to return a relationship property (called `proportion`) plus the sum of that property for all relationship matched by a Cypher query in Neo4j. I've gotten this far:

```
START alice=node(3) 
MATCH p=(alice)<-[r:SUPPORTED_BY]-(n) 
RETURN reduce(total=0, rel in relationships(p): total + rel.proportion), sum(r.proportion) AS total;
```

This returns:

```
+-----------------+
| reduced | total |
+-----------------+
| 2       | 2     |
| 1       | 1     |
+-----------------+
```

where I was expecting:

```
+-----------------+
| reduced | total |
+-----------------+
| 2       | 3     |
| 1       | 3     |
+-----------------+
```

As a beginner user of Cypher, I'm not really sure how to approach this query; I'm clearly not using `reduce` correctly. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `WITH` to split up the query into two parts:

1. find the sum of all proportions, and pass that as bound name to the next part
2. find the individual proportions

.

```
START alice=node(3)
MATCH alice<-[r:SUPPORTED_BY]-() 
WITH sum(r.proportion) AS total 
MATCH alice<-[r:SUPPORTED_BY]-(other) 
RETURN other.name, r.proportion, total
```

Comment: As an explanation, the problem with your original query was that sum() also ALWAYS performs an aggregation(ie. groupBy), which in your case was the first column.

Comment: +1 Reduce is mainly useful for variable length paths or collections--if you've got the values in different "intermediate results" or "rows" already, you can use the standard aggregation functions as shown here.